# Android Angularjs Text to Speech

Tags: javascript, java, android, angularjs, text-to-speech

I've had some trouble using the TextToSpeech class on Android. To explain better my problem, I have to explain that I use only java, a webview page and angular to communicate the front-end with my back-end.

This is my html file that calls my angular function, that then calls a java function

```html
<body ng-controller="speechController">
    <div class="speech-container">
        <div class="page-container">
            <div class="page-content">
                <div class="content-wrapper">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn bg-pink-400 btn-block" ng-click="talk()">Pressione para falar... <i class="icon-arrow-right14 position-right"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn bg-pink-400 btn-block" ng-click="listen()">Pressione para ouvir... <i class="icon-arrow-right14 position-right"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is what my java function looks like. The main problem is that the line that reads "tts.speak" is not working correctly, I have instanced the Variable "tts" and implemented the TextToSpeech.OnInitListener, I have no idea what is causing the variable to remain as null.

```java
 @JavascriptInterface
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") // Support older API levels too.
    public void speak(String text, Boolean override) {
        text="teste2";           
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. All I had to do was add the following code to my onCreate():

```
tts=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
                }
            }
        });
```